# sorting multiple pandas columns and calculating value percent greater than zero

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sorting, counting

I have a pandas dataframe I melted together with each row being a different single-cell gene expression. I want to sort by metadata columns ('patient ID', 'Cluster ID', 'Gene ID') and count how many cells have a value greater than zero in the 'value' column.

Next I want to divide that by the total value of cells in that 'cluster ID' within that 'patient ID'. I am not 100% sure how to do this. I tried something like

```
df = df.groupby(['patient ID', 'Cluster ID', 'Gene ID']).size().reset_index(name='counts')
```

to get a `df` with total numbers of cells within a cluster by patient expressing a gene. I still need a way to sort them by those with the 'value' column higher than zero and then divide to get my final values.

When I try something like

```
df["Counts > 0"]= df.groupby(['patient ID', 'Cluster ID', 'Gene ID'])['value'].gt(0).sum()
```

I get an error saying:

```
AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'gt'
```

Edit: example

```
data = {'Patient ID':['C100', 'C100', 'C100', 'C101', 'C102', 'C103'],
    'Cluster ID':['ID 1', 'ID 2', 'ID 2', 'ID 2', 'ID 3', 'ID4'],
    'Gene ID':['Gene 1', 'Gene 1', 'Gene 2', 'Gene 2', 'Gene 3', 'Gene 4'],
    'Expression Value':[0, 0, 5, 0, 20, 5],
   }


# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  
# Print the output.
df
```

[EXAMPLE but it gets much bigger and complicated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9lkD.png)

for every combination of patient ID, Cluster ID, Gene ID, how do I count the sum of them? sum of them greater than zero in 'value'? Divide the two of them to find the % of cells positive for a gene ID within a cluster within a patient.

Comment: could you give a example df input?

Comment: @DaSong I just edited and updated the post with an example!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found a way to get what I want:

total counts:

```
CRC_Merge_GD_total_TEST = CRC_GD_Melt_1.groupby(['HTO_secondID', 'new_clusters_3', 'variable'])['value'].agg(pos=lambda ts: (ts.ge(0)).sum()) 

CRC_Merge_GD_total_TEST = CRC_Merge_GD_total_TEST.rename(columns={"pos": "Sum of total"})
```

total counts greater than zero:

```
CRC_Merge_GD_over_zero = CRC_GD_Melt_1.groupby(['HTO_secondID', 'new_clusters_3', 'variable'])['value'].agg(pos=lambda ts: (ts > 0).sum()) 

CRC_Merge_GD_over_zero = CRC_Merge_GD_over_zero.rename(columns={"pos": "Sum gt zero"})
```

Combine:

```
df_new = CRC_Merge_GD_total_TEST.merge(CRC_Merge_GD_over_zero, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Calculate % positive:

```
df_new['pct pos'] = df_new['Sum gt zero']/df_new['Sum of total'] * 100
```